# visual studio 2013 on msdn includes update 4?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, updates

i have visual studio 2013 installed and i download the update 4 package of 5.8gb but i am getting installation error "KB2829760LP The digital signature of the object did not verify." so i thought i should download the fresh visual studio 2013 package rather than trying to update what i currently have. so i searched over the internet and cant find out exactly if the current visual studio 2013 download package that is available on visualstudio.com includes the recently released update 4. what i am trying to ask is, if i download fresh vs2013 installation package from visualstudio.com will i still need to do update 4 seperately or it is already updated?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear where do you got your image from (visualstudio.com **or** from your MSDN subscription).

Nevertheless, both sites contain image downloads for Visual Studio including Update 4. You can see it directly on the [visualstudio.com download page](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) or when you are in the download area of your MSDN subscription.

Comment: i think i still couldnot make myself clear, i am trying to ask, if i download vs2013 from visualstudio.com today. will i need to download the update 4 package serperately to update it or will it come pre-updated?

Comment: As shown in the link I provided above this package already contains Update 4. So, there's no need to install it separately.